# Linked List removing all instances of a specified value

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a lot of trouble having this remove all the instances of the same value in a linked list. I understand the problem has something to do with the self.head part of the remove function.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None


def getData(self):
    return self.data

def getNext(self):
    return self.next

def setData(self,newdata):
    self.data = newdata

def setNext(self,newnext):
    self.next = newnext


class UnorderedList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

#Checks to see if the list is empty
def isEmpty(self):
    return self.head == None

#Adds the item at the beginning of the list
def add(self,item):        
    temp = Node(item)
    temp.setNext(self.head)
    self.head = temp

#Prints the Unordered List
def __str__(self):
    result = "["
    current = self.head
    if current != None:
        result += str(current.data)
        current = current.next
        while current:
            result += ", " + str(current.data)
            current = current.next
    result += "]"
    return result  

# Removes a specified item from the list
def remove(self, item):
    if self.head == None:
         return 'Cannot remove from an empty list'

    current = self.head     
    while current != None:
        iterator = current
        while iterator != None:
            prev = iterator
            iterator = iterator.getNext()
            if iterator is None:
                break
            if iterator.getData() == item:
                Next = iterator.getNext()
                prev.setNext(Next)
        current = current.getNext()



mylist = UnorderedList()

for i in range(50):
    mylist.add(2)
mylist.remove(2)
print(mylist)
```

result: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

expected result: []

Answer (score 0):

I think your `remove` code is a bit more complicated than it needs to be (with nested loops and such). You should be able to make it work a little bit more simply.

Here's how I'd do it with two loops, one after the other. The first loop is for leading nodes with the value you're removing in them. The second loop is for handling the rest of the list.

```
def remove(self, item):
    if self.head == None:
        return 'Cannot remove from an empty list' # note, you may want to raise an exception

    while self.head is not None and self.head.data == item: # first loop, for leading values
        self.head = self.head.next

    if self.head is not None: # rest is only needed if the first loop didn't empty the list
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None: # second loop, over all later items
            if current.next.data == item: # check for matching items
                current.next = current.next.next # and remove them
            else:
                current = current.next
```

I've left out the calls to the getter and setter functions you have because they're distracting and usually not necessary in Python code. There's a good reason to use getter and setter functions in other languages, but it's usually fine to just use attributes directly in Python (you can later turn them into `property` descriptors if you need to change how they are implemented without changing the API). If this is for a homework assignment, you'll probably need to go in a fix that up.

As I commented in the code, it might also be appropriate to use something like `raise ValueError("cannot remove from an empty list")` in the first `if` block rather than returning that error message as a string. The `remove` method doesn't normally return anything (which is the same as returning `None`) so there's a good chance a return value not be noticed unless you're calling the function from an interactive session. Exceptions are much more useful, since they break up the program flow when they happen where they're not expected (which is good for debugging).

Comment: Yeah, I like the suggestion to raise an exception a lot more. I'm lost as to why the third statement (if self.head is not None)  runs to infinity. For instance under this input    mylist = UnorderedList()

for i in range(50):
    mylist.add(2)
mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(77)
mylist.add(17)
mylist.add(93)
mylist.add(26)
mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(54)
print(mylist)
mylist.remove(2)
print(mylist)

Comment: Oh, it runs forever because I was dumb and left out any code to advance `current` to a later node. You only want that to happen when you haven't just removed an item though. I've edited with code that hopefully won't run forever.